# Zend 2 Paginator how does it work?

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2, zend-paginator

I'm trying to understand the `Zend Paginator` and would mostly like to make sure it doesn't break my scripts.

For example, I have the following snippet which successfully loads some contacts one at a time:

```
$offset = 1;
//returns a paginator instance using a dbSelect;
$contacts = $ContactsMapper->fetchAll($fetchObj);

$contacts->setCurrentPageNumber($offset);
$contacts->setItemCountPerPage(1);

$allContacts = count($contacts);
while($allContacts >= $offset) {
    foreach($contacts as $contact) {
        //do something
    }
    $offset++;
    $contacts->setCurrentPageNumber($offset);
    $contacts->setItemCountPerPage(1);
}
```

However I can have hundreds of thousands of contacts in the database and matched by the `SELECT` I send to the paginator. Can I be sure it only loads one at a time in this example? And how does it do it, does it run a customized query with `limit` and `offset`?

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation : [Zend Paginator Usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html)

> **Note**
>
> ---
>
> Instead of selecting every matching row of a given query, the `DbSelect`
>   adapter retrieves only the smallest amount of data necessary for
>   displaying the current page. Because of this, a second query is
>   dynamically generated to determine the total number of matching rows.

If your using [Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html#the-dbselect-adapter) it will apply `limit` and `offset` to the query you're passing it, and it will just fetch the wanted records. This is done in the `getItems()` function of `DbSelect`, you could see that [these lines](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Paginator/Adapter/DbSelect.php#L97-98) in the source code.

You could also read this from the documentation :

> This adapter does **not** fetch all records from the database in order
>   to count them. Instead, the adapter manipulates the original query to
>   produce a corresponding *COUNT* query. Paginator then executes that
>   *COUNT* query to get the number of rows. This does require an extra round-trip to the database, but this is many times faster than
>   fetching an entire result set and using `count()`, especially with
>   large collections of data.